# Netty 4.0.19.Final Memory Leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, netty

I seem to be experiencing recurring memory issues with Netty 4. My app queries Minecraft servers for information and updates a database with that information. Currently it creates 300 connection requests every 10 seconds and sends packets if those connections are successfully completed.

A previous iteration of my querying app used Netty 3.2.5 and it ran for months on end nonstop with no issues. With Netty 4 however, it only runs a few hours before exhausting all available resources. Here is a screenshot of the memory sampling over a JMX connection.

[image: Memory sampling results]

As we can see, `io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer$Entry` is using up a large amount of memory. Any idea how to go about troubleshooting this? I'm available to provide code if you guys need. Thanks!

**Edit: This is not a duplicate of "How to find a Java memory leak". This has to do with Netty specifically, and I'm not trying to find out how to discover a memory leak - I've already discovered one with Netty.**

Comment: Even if it is not a duplicate, it's still too broad to be answered, so I'm voting for it to remain closed. From what I can tell, all you have done is provide a screenshot of the memory usage, but haven't actually provided any code. Add some code to your answer and make it actually answerable and vote to open it again.

Comment: I voted to reopen because it's not a duplicate, but @Mike has a point; this question should have been put on hold due to lacking sufficient information. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: This is a problem with the Netty library. If you go to their website (netty.io), they handle all support through Stack Overflow. I would like to leave the question open so that they can come along and answer it for me.